# What cause the width of the element with position: fixed not relative to the viewport

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, position

The code below is how I implement modals(popup screen).

```js
$('.h-modal-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.h-modal-bg').addClass('h-modal-bg-show');
      $('.h-modal').addClass('h-modal-show');
})
$('.h-modal-bg').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
          $('.h-modal-bg').removeClass('h-modal-bg-show');
          $('.h-modal').removeClass('h-modal-show');
      }
})
```

```css
.h-modal-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.48);
  z-index: 10000;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.h-modal-bg-show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.h-modal {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: -40px auto 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  /*Uncomment if more animation is needed*/
  /*opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;*/
}
.h-modal-show {
  /*Uncomment if more animation is needed*/
  /*opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);*/
}
.h-modal-header {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.h-modal-red .h-modal-header {
  background-color: #DE0716;
  color: #FFF;
}
.h-modal-black .h-modal-header {
  background-color: #343434;
  color: #FFF;
}
.h-modal-content {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="h-modal-btn">Choose Location</button>
<div class="h-modal-bg">
    <div class="h-modal h-modal-black">
        <div class="h-modal-header">
             Choose Location
        </div>
        <div class="h-modal-content"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Please pay attention on the `.h-modal` class and `.h-modal-show` class. The code been commented is the problem. As you can see, my code now is work, every element is placed on the right place. But when I uncomment those code, the size of the modal header is not relative to the size of the viewport. Please someone correct my notions about positioning, thank you!